# How to use elliptic filter in matlab for edf data

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have used edfread in order to read EEG data, which I have stored into a variable called plotData. I want to know how I can implement an elliptic filter,to extract 7-9 Hz (alpha band) from one of the channels.

The EDF data stored in plotData looks like the below.

```
plotData = 

            ver: 0
      patientID: 'test                                                                            '
       recordID: 'test                                                                            '
      startdate: '23.06.16'
      starttime: '12.10.38'
          bytes: 9472
        records: 3
       duration: 1
             ns: 36
          label: {1x36 cell}
     transducer: {1x36 cell}
          units: {1x36 cell}
    physicalMin: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    physicalMax: [1x36 double]
     digitalMin: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     digitalMax: [1x36 double]
      prefilter: {1x36 cell}
        samples: [1x36 double]
```

Comment: Hi. I think your question is not really limited to EDF files. But: design your filter dependant on your sample frequency used in the EDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your EDF data provided correctly, there are 36 samples (`ns`) over a `duration` of 1 second, which gives you a sampling rate of 36Hz.

The design of a digital elliptic filter can then be done using the builtin [`ellip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/ellip.html) function. You will need to fill in your filter requirements for the passband ripples, stopband attenuation and transition bands. With some parameters provided as example, this would look like:

```
fs    = 36; % sampling rate in Hz
fmin  = 7;  % minimum passband frequency in Hz
fmax  = 9;  % maximum passband frequency in Hz
order = 5;  % filter order (the higher the narrower the transition band)
Rs    = 20; % stopband attenuation in dB
Rp    = 1;  % passband ripples in dB

[b,a] = ellip(order, Rp, Rs, [fmin/(fs/2), fmax/(fs/2)]);
```

You can then visualize the resulting response with [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) (and adjust as required). For the above parameters, the frequency response would look like:

[image]

Finally, to filter out your data you'd use the [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function with the above designed filter coefficients `a` and `b` and your input `plotData`:

```
filtered_data = filter(b,a,plotData);
```